# wpf TabItem binding IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged, tabitem, isenabled

I would like to bind the `IsEnabled` property of `TabItem` to data within my code.

e.g. I have a `TabItem` defined as follows

```
<TabItem Name="Tab1" Header="Tab1" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Tab1Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}">
</TabItem>
```

And I have defined a data class which inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` as follows

```
class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    } 
    public bool Tab1Enabled
    {
        get{ return m_tab1Enabled; }
        set
        {
            m_tab1Enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tab1Enabled");
        }
    }            
}
```

Then I set the `DataContext` to my data member.

```
public partial class MyApp : Window
{
    MyData m_myData = new MyData();
    MyApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = m_myData;
    }
}
```

However, when the Tab1Enabled property gets set programatically, the PropertyChanged event is null and so the notification event is not sent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dunno if it's the problem, but I wouldn't do any kind of UI code ahead of `InializeComponent()`

Comment: Also try adding Mode="TwoWay" to the binding

Comment: `m_myData` and `m_bindingData` are two different variables. Is that a typo?

Comment: I tried setting the data context after the InitializeComponent(), set the mode to TwoWay but no difference. Also, yes this was a type.

Comment: There's no reason why your code shouldn't work. I've made a program based on your code and it works flawlessly. My hunch is that you're changing the datacontext dynamically to something else in runtime or you're doing some voodoo-magic that you're not telling us about.

Comment: Thanks. Yes my code was performing some voodoo. The datacontext was being set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you need to change  m_bindinData to the variable you want to bind to (m_myData). I fired up VS2012 and tested your code. Setting `m_myData.Tab1Enabled = true;` set the tab to enabled and setting `m_myData.Tab1Enabled = false;` disabled it correctly. Heres what I had.

```
public partial class MyApp : Window
{
    MyData m_myData = new MyData();
    MyApp()
    {
        this.DataContext = m_myData;
        InitializeComponent();

        m_myData.Tab1Enabled = true;
    }
}

class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public bool Tab1Enabled
    {
        get { return m_tab1Enabled; }
        set
        {
            m_tab1Enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tab1Enabled");
        }
    }

    private bool m_tab1Enabled;
}

<TabControl>
    <TabItem Name="Tab1" Header="Tab1" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Tab1Enabled}">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Name="Tab2" Header="Tab2">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?  Notice the PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = PropertyChanged; line in the OnPropertyChanged method.

```
class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    } 
    public bool Tab1Enabled
    {
        get{ return m_tab1Enabled; }
        set
        {
            m_tab1Enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tab1Enabled");
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `TabItem` might not inheriting `DataContext` of your `Window`. Try looking into the `output window`, `binding failure error` will be there.

As a workaround you can use `RelativeSource` to travel upto the `DataContext` of your window and bind with its related property like this -

```
<TabItem Name="Tab1" Header="Tab1"
         IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.Tab1Enabled,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                   AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```